# xpages Tabbed Panel printing

Tags: xpages, printing-web-page

I'm sure I am missing something straightforward and simple, but in xpages, using a tabbed panel, who do I get all the tabs to print when the users prints the page?

Comment: Make special page for printing. Hidden tabs are not part of the page (DOM) so usual CSS magic won't help.

Comment: Also, if you're using the standard tabbed panel component (as opposed to the Dojo tab container), the contents of the unselected tabs aren't even in the DOM... a full refresh event is required to retrieve the data for the newly selected tab, at which point the data for the previously selected tab is no longer in the DOM. On a side note, have you confirmed there is a valid need to print in the first place? Besides, of course, "we want to"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a Dojo tab container (part of the extension library) instead of the standard tabbed panel. With the Dojo tab container the content of all tabs is loaded at once (in opposite to the standard tabbed panel, as Tim said), so you could do some CSS magic to make all tabs visible when printing.

Tim recommends building a separate XPage for printing, and I second that. Organize the content of the tabs in custom controls, create a new XPage for example with the suffix "_print" and include the custom controls in it without the tabbed panel. Then create a button, link or whatever in the first XPage which simple opens an XPage with the same name plus "_print" in a new window.

In the "_print" Xpage you can use a "window.print" after the page loads to open the print dialog automatically.

This technique has the advantage that you can style the printing exactly as needed. You can even control which content to include when printing by using the visible/rendered property and compute to render controls only when the current page name does not include "_print".

Comment: Second page created, works like a champion.  Don't know how I had not ran into this previously, but someone wants to be able to take printed information to the hospital with a client so apparently there is a need to print in this case.

Comment: i'm trying to do something similar with an ExtLib Dialog control.  I use a viewScope var to open a document in the Dialog control.  I have a print button on the Dialog control. I launch a print xpage with the print button, but I'm having a problem getting the data to show up on the print xpage.  Any ideas?